# Create a child model in rails (belongs_to) and pre-setting the parent ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, models, formtastic

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but not being aware of the right terminology in Rails, I can't find what I'm looking for....

A `Project` model has_many `Task`, and a `Task` belongs_to a `Project`.

My `routes.rb` has

```
resources :projects
resources :tasks
```

I can create/edit/modify `Projects` just fine, and I can also edit `Tasks`... but I can't seem to work out how to create a new `Task`, assigning the correct `Project` when doing so.

My `Project` page (eg. /projects/2) has an Add Task link which goes to /task/new, so I'm losing the connection. I don't want to make a nested resource, because `Tasks`, once created, will be uniquely identifiable by their ID, and in future has_many other models as well.

Is there a quick fix here?

**edit** Well I've managed to solve this.... it's ugly and it's horrible and I'm not sure why it has to be that way, but it works.

My routes:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tasks, :only => [:new]
end

resources :tasks, :except => [:new]
```

My task controller:

```
def new
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @task = @project.tasks.build
end

# Process the form for creating a new task.
def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:task][:project_id])
  @task = @project.tasks.build(params[:task])
  if @task.save
    flash[:success] = 'Task created.'
    redirect_to project_path(@project)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

And my Task form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @task do |f| %>

<%= render 'shared/form_message', :object => f.object %>

<%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :project %>
<% end %>

<ul class="formActions">
    <li class="list"><%= link_to 'Back to list', project_path(@task.project) %></li>
    <li><%= f.submit "Save" %></li>
</ul>

<% end %>
```

I didn't want to have to put the project box on the form, and I'm still not sure why I have to, and also why I needed to take :create *out* of the nested routes. It also seems quite laborous, for such a common task, but it works, so.... I guess it's all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT sounds like what you want is a nested route for creating tasks only.

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tasks, :only=>[:new, :create]
end
resources :tasks, :except=>[:new, :create]
```

**EDIT**: Here's a revised version of your code that should be a bit cleaner. With a little borrowing from [edgerunner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311941/edgerunner).

Task controller:

```
before_filter :get_project

def new
  @task = Task.new
end

# Process the form for creating a new task.
def create
  @task = Task.new params[:task]
  @task.project_id = params[:project_id]
  if @task.save
    flash[:success] = 'Task created.'
    redirect_to project_path(@task.project_id)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def get_project
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end
```

And the Task form:

```
<%= form_for [@project, @task] do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/form_message', :object => f.object %>

  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
  <% end %>

  <ul class="formActions">
    <li class="list"><%= link_to 'Back to list', project_path(@task.project) %></li>
    <li><%= f.submit "Save" %></li>
  </ul>

<% end %>
```

Comment: hmm, that has changed my routes... but I'm still having a bit of trouble. I've made changes to my TaskController so that it now creates Tasks through the parent Project but... it's still not working. :(

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials that do this kind of thing, start to end?

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources

Comment: augh I am getting *so* close to figuring this out, but still no dice... it looks all good to me, but the destination of my task create form stubbornly insists on being /tasks, even though the create action is a nested route... I think if I can figure this out, I'll have it.

Comment: Using form_for([@project, @task]) should get you the right route. You could also try form_for(project_tasks_path(@project.id)). Either should work.

Comment: I had missed that form_for[@project, @task] and I had just figured it out by myself... why did I not get notified about your comments earlier, I wonder! Anyway it's all solved now, and more importantly, I understand *why* it works. Thank you **so** much.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you build your new task through your project in your new task action so that it will come with the project ID already assigned. That should make your form generator behave nicely and do the right thing.

```
TasksController < AplicationController
  before_filter :get_project
  …
  def new
    @task = @project.tasks.build # don't use @task = Task.new here!
  end
  …
  def get_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end
end
```

of course it is highly recommended to use nested routes with this.

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tasks
end
```